# compare each value before in array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i have an response from my mongodb as result of my aggregation function using mongopaginateaggregate as below:

```
const data = {
  docs: [
    {
      Material_Description: 'NABATI VITAKRIM RSY 122g MT (24 pcs)',
      Plant: 'K105',
      Channel: 'MT',
      Material: '300973',
      expiredDate: 'January-2024',
      '2023-04-12': 124
    },
    {
      Material_Description: 'NEXTAR GANDUMKU RCO 22g GT(10pc x 12bal)',
      Plant: 'K105',
      Channel: 'GT',
      Material: '303923',
      expiredDate: 'October-2023',
      '2023-04-12': 1
    }
  ],
  totalDocs: 2,
  limit: 1000,
  page: 1,
  totalPages: 1,
  pagingCounter: 1,
  hasPrevPage: false,
  hasNextPage: false,
  prevPage: null,
  nextPage: null
}
```

i try to group it and compare each value by adding function datelist:

```
const dateLists = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, index) => {
        const local = new Date();
        local.setDate(local.getDate() - index);
        return local.toLocaleDateString("en-SE", {
          timeZone: "Asia/Jakarta",
        });
      });
```

here is my try and my result:
i succeed adding other dates to the data but failed to compare each date value to get the comparasion:

```
const new_data = data.docs.map((item) => {
        const newItem = {
          Material: item.Material,
          Material_Description: item.Material_Description,
          Plant: item.Plant,
          Channel: item.Channel,
          expiredDate: item.expiredDate,
        };
        let a = 1;

        dateLists.sort().forEach((date) => {
          newItem[date] = item[date] ? item[date] : 0;

          // `${'Keterangan_'+ parseStr(a)}` = item[date] ? item[date] : 0;
        });
        return newItem;
      });

      data.docs = new_data;
```

result:

```
{
        "docs": [
            {
                "Material": "300973",
                "Material_Description": "NABATI VITAKRIM RSY 122g MT (24 pcs)",
                "Plant": "K105",
                "Channel": "MT",
                "expiredDate": "January-2024",
                "2023-04-12": 124,
                "2023-04-13": 0,
                "2023-04-14": 0,
                "2023-04-15": 0,
                "2023-04-16": 1,
                "2023-04-17": 0,
                "2023-04-18": 0
            },
            {
                "Material": "303923",
                "Material_Description": "NEXTAR GANDUMKU RCO 22g GT(10pc x 12bal)",
                "Plant": "K105",
                "Channel": "GT",
                "expiredDate": "October-2023",
                "2023-04-12": 1,
                "2023-04-13": 0,
                "2023-04-14": 0,
                "2023-04-15": 0,
                "2023-04-16": 0,
                "2023-04-17": 0,
                "2023-04-18": 0
            }
        ],
        "totalDocs": 2,
        "limit": 1000,
        "page": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "pagingCounter": 1,
        "hasPrevPage": false,
        "hasNextPage": false,
        "prevPage": null,
        "nextPage": null
    }
```

is that possible to compare each value of the date like this?:

[image]

here is my expected resulted that when compare each value of the date inside the object:

```
"docs": [
            {
                "Material": "300973",
                "Material_Description": "NABATI VITAKRIM RSY 122g MT (24 pcs)",
                "Plant": "K105",
                "Channel": "MT",
                "expiredDate": "January-2024",
                "2023-04-12": 124,
                "Keterangan_1":"No Data",
                "2023-04-13": 0,
                "Keterangan_2":"Berkurang",
                "2023-04-14": 0,
                "Keterangan_3":"Sama",
                "2023-04-15": 0,
                "Keterangan_4":"Sama",
                "2023-04-16": 1,
                "Keterangan_5":"Bertambah",
                "2023-04-17": 0,
                "Keterangan_6":"Berkurang",
                "2023-04-18": 0,
                "Keterangan_7":"Sama",
            },
```

any help on this... or any one can help to improve my code to get the expected result

Comment: Can you please explain that what is the Keterangan_number related with and you are asking to compare each value of the date with expiredDate ?